# Multiple delivery confirmations per message with Ruby SMPP

Tags: ruby, smpp

I am using the ruby smpp library to send/receive SMS. Right now we are sending messages to two different servers, using the ruby-smpp library. One of them works perfectly, but the other one sends multiple DELIVRD confirmations for each messages. And by multiple I mean hundreds of confirmations per message in some cases.

Does anyone know any possible reason behind this? I am thinking on something relative to the implementation of the protocol the company is using, since it works perfectly with the other one, and not on the lines of a bug in the specific smpp ruby library. We are using smpp v3.4.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Ruby library yet, but I'll tap my basic SMPP knowledge to attempt an answer...

It sounds like you are asking for a delivery acknowledgement, but your server is not acknowledging the receipt of the delivery acknowledgement.

Page 31 of the SMPP v3.4 spec shows:

(you are on the left)

submit_sm ->
<- submit_sm_resp

<- deliver_sm
deliver_sm_resp ->

You could do a submit_sm without delivery receipt.